# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio 2013 and getting this error.

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   CAIUInterface * __cdecl :GetInstance(void)"
>   (?GetInstance@CAIUInterface@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function
>   "public: int call CAppAIUInterface::CloseApp(void)"
>   (?CloseApp@CAppAIUInterface@@QAEHXZ)  D:\15008_CPDS\CPDS\AppAIUInterface.obj  CPDS

`CAIUInterface` is a singleton class.

```
 // below is CAIUInterface.h
#include "std429.h"
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class CAppAIUInterface; 
class CAIUInterface
{
private:
    static bool m_bInstanceFlag;                    
    static CAIUInterface *m_objAIU;                     

protected:
    CAIUInterface();

public:
    //Destructor
    ~CAIUInterface();
    static CAIUInterface* GetInstance();
    int Close();
};

// CAIUInterface.cpp file

#include <windows.h>
#include "AIUInterface.h"
using namespace std::placeholders;

bool CAIUInterface::m_bInstanceFlag = false;    
CAIUInterface* CAIUInterface::m_objAIU = NULL;
CAIUInterface* CAIUInterface::GetInstance()
{
    if (!m_bInstanceFlag)
    {
        m_objAIU = new CAIUInterface();
        m_bInstanceFlag = true;
    }
    return m_objAIU;
}


// APPAIUInterface.h 
#include "Transmitter.h"
class CAppAIUInterface
{
private:
    CTransmitter            m_objTrans;
public:
    CAppAIUInterface();
    ~CAppAIUInterface();
    int CloseApp();
};

// APPAIUInterface.cpp 
int CAppAIUInterface::CloseApp()
{
    unsigned int siResult = 0;
    siResult = CAIUInterface::GetInstance()->Close();
    if (siResult != CPDS_SUCCESS)
        return ERR_APP_AIU_CLOSE;
    return CPDS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You *do* include the source file where `CAIUInterface::GetInstance` is defined in your project? And please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for your quick replay. I included the source file.

Comment: Did the source file inclusion solve the problem?

Comment: no, it still showing the same error.

Comment: There is not enough detail here to diagnose the cause of the error. Work through all the answers to this question; http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/3747990.